# Why Python evaluates this to true?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I come from C background and found this quite strange.

```
a = 0

b = 0

if (a == b) != 0:
    print('non zero and equal')
else:
    print('something wrong')
```

This prints "non zero and equal".

In C, `a == b` evaluates to `true`, i.e. non-zero. 
Now, you compare non-zero with zero and this comes to `false`, i.e. 0.

How does this work in Python?

I tried doing something like this:

```
if a==b !=0:
```

It worked but I got to know there is some lazy evaluation there and I need to understand it.

Comment: You might like to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: (a == b) gets evaluated first due to parentheses, so effectively you are evaluating True != 0 which is True as True equates to 1

Comment: In C, `int a = 0; int b = 0; return (a == b) != 0;`, you get `1`, because you used `!=` for the final 0 comparison. The same thing happens here.

Comment: As others have said, you're mistaken about how C works. It behaves the same as Python here (aside from the first comparison producing `1`, not a special `True` value, but Python's `True` has a numeric value of `1` so it's all basically the same).

Comment: The result of comparison of values of a==b is True, which you then, compare with numerical value 0, which is evaluates to False.

Answer (score 0):

`a==b` comes to `True`.

Also, `True != 0` which evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

It same as C, when `a == b` it comes out to be `true` which is `1`

```
(a == b) != 0
```

gives

```
1!= 0
```

and hence the print statement

Comment: `True == 1` but `True is not 1`

Comment: It is of type bool. Try `type(a==b)`. It will give you `bool` and not `str`. Which is effectively 1

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 True evaluates to 1 and False as 0. Find below for more understanding.
Also read this [operator comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) to clear your understanding.

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True != 0
True
>>> False != 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True == 4
False
```